# Is "Kent" in Tashkent of Turkic origin or Indo-European?

Tags: etymology, indo-european, turkish, persian, turkic-languages

In *Turkish* there is this word **Kent** which means city. Some Turkic city names have this as a suffix, like **Başkent** and **Tashkent**. In *Azerbaijani* the same word, with the spelling of **Kənd** (**Kand**) means village and we have tens of villages in Iranian Azerbaijan and Republic of Azerbaijan with their names ending in **Kənd**: *Təzəkənd*, *sarikənd*, *qoşakənd*, *yengikənd*, and etc.

In Persian cities and villages and even the language itself, I have not seen any usage of this word. I saw a statement in Wikipedia which claimed that this word is of *Sogdian* origin and is related to the Persian word of **کندن** (**Kandan**), which literally means **digging**, and metaphorically refers to an inhabited place.

Does someone have more information about the etymology of this word/suffix?

Comment: http://dictionaries.brillonline.com/iranian (Cheung 2007) gives **Proto-Iranian *kanH 'to dig'**, cf. YAv. ºkan- ‘to dig’, Old Persian ka(n)- ‘to dig’, OKh. kaggan- ‘to dig’, BSogd. kn- ‘to put out (eye)’ etc. and **suggests an Indo-European etymology**, linking it to **PIE ? *kenH1- ‘to dig’**

Comment: In Kurdish Gund means willage.
Gund <- Gand <- Kand and i am agree with "If KAND is from altaic origin, there must ctys in Altay with KAND. But al of the citys with the name KAND ara in Iranian influence area".

Comment: Is the Arabic tribe Banu Kindah also related?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the monumental [Old Turkic Dictionary](http://altaica.narod.ru/LIBRARY/e_dts.htm) ("Древнетюркский словарь", Наука, Л., 1969) it is written that **Kent/Kənd** is really of the Sogdian origin. The dictionary reflects the words found in the Turkic written records of the 7th - 13th centuries.

The word **Kent** is not there, but the word **Kend** redirects to **Känd**, to page 290, and here is the screenshot of the **Känd** (city) entry. Notice the remark "[*согд.* k'nδ] after the headword," 'согд.' means 'Sogdian':

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much. What about the relation with Persian **Kandan** is it mentioned here? Sorry that I couldn't read Russian.

Comment: @Mousa - No, it's not mentioned in the dictionary, there're only translated examples of usage. But it really looks like there's a connection of this word with digging, even in Sogdian. You can [download the "Sogdian Dictionary (Sogdian-Persian-English)"](http://en.bookfi.org/book/1116890) by B. Gharib. The entry for 'city', _knδ_, is #4769, page 190 (notice also entries ##4757 - 4760), and 'to dig' is _kn-_, page 189, so the 2 words can well be connected. Other words related to 'dig' are _knt-_ 'dig out' (#4769) and _qnyy_ 'digger' (#4789), the last one was probably pronounced [kane:].

Comment: Well, somebody should update https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kent#Turkish, they say it's from proto-Turkic *konmak*.

Comment: On the other hand, https://tr.wiktionary.org/wiki/kent says Sogdian.

Answer (score 2):

It may be of interest to note, that کندن shows a root-dualism. The Old Indian form of the root is **khan**, similar Pāzand **χandan**. So, the New Persian words **χān**/**χāne**, "house" derives from the same root as **kent**. This shows, that it is quite plausible that a word denoting a place to live should derive from the root "to dig". On the other hand it maybe explains, why you did not find any use of the word **kent** in Persian.

Comment: Oh, that was indeed interesting, thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 1):

In modern Sanskrit and Hindi "khand" (the "and" is pronounced as the "und" of hundred) means a part or a division. In India the names of  many regions (both contemporary as well as ancient), have the word "khand" as a suffix, eg Uttara_khand is a state in India..(lit meaning northern division) . In India Khand is rarely seen in the name of a city or village.

The word "Khan" (the "an" is pronounced as the "an" in want) in modern Hindi means a mine (like a coal-mine).. so there is an association with digging.

I do not know if the words Khand and Khan come from a  common older root.

Answer (score -3):

May be that will help you. Pl let me know, if you need more information

[image: Altaic-Turkic etymology of the word kan or ken-o]

Comment: Can you please cite the source where you got the screen shot from? Without a proper attribution the screen shot is worthless.

Comment: The sourse is actualy below. "Fedotov, "Doubts about the OT words", Clark 1977.

Answer (score -3):

If KAND is from altaic origin, there must ctys in Altay with KAND. But al of the citys with the name KAND ara in Iranian influence area.

Comment: this gives a hint but does not provide an evidence or proof.

Answer (score -4):

I think "kot" and "kan" are enough evidence to think that the word "kand" is Altaic origine. 
[image: Another possible Altaic-Turkic word for village or settlement.]

Comment: I see you have written 3 answers here that refer to each other. This is discouraged on Stack Exchange sites. Instead of that, please use the "edit" link below your post, and write all the relevant information within one post.

Comment: Where this unsourced entry is from there doesn't seem to be anything in it to link it to *kent*.

Comment: The screens are from data base of ancient words, made by Russian Academy of Science. http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/main.cgi?root=config&morpho=0

Comment: starling.rinet.ru